# Does there exist an identity function when sets are not equal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions

Let $X \ne Y$ be any two sets. Is it possible to define an "identity function" from $Y$ to $X$?

Comment: what is an identity function?

Comment: f(a)=a it returns the same element .

Comment: If the domain of the identity function is $A$, then what is the codomain (by the standard definition of an identity function)? What is *your* definition of an identity function when the domain and codomain are different?

Comment: The Domain is any set X and co-domain is Y in the above case and they are not equal so i have to prove that there is an identity function from X to Y.

Comment: What would your definition be? Would it make sense? What is $x$ mapped to if $x\in X$ but $x\notin Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be conceivable if $X\subset Y$. Then we could maybe define $\mathbb{I}_X:X\to Y$ by $\mathbb{I}_X(x)=x$, for any $x\in X$. Such a function would be a bijection from $X$ to itself, essentially disregarding $Y$.

If however, $X\not\subset Y$, i.e. $\exists x\in X,$ with  $x\not\in Y$; then it seems impossible to define an identity function $\mathbb{I}_X:X\to Y$ such that $\mathbb{I}_X(x)=x$. In this case $Y$ would not be an appropriate codomain.